# R: console not showing all results

Tags: r, console

I am using the MixRasch package, calling a function whose output is a list. The list is extremely long and I cannot scroll up in the console to see all the results inside. I am using R studio. I tried exporting the list using dput, but it is completely unreadable (even playing around with the parsing options.)

Can you suggest other ways to export the list or read the results from the console?

Comment: Perhaps you don't need to review all the data, but a sample?  I typically use a combination of str(list) and names(list) to filter down to ones I can inspect, so then the output is more manageable - you can then view via list[names(list)1][[1]]$inner_name[1] etc.

Comment: Good suggestions, that's what I will do!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957308/write-a-list-as-seen-in-r-console-output-into-a-text-file/29957559#29957559 might help

Answer (score 1):

Using RStudio if you **really** need to see all the results of your list you can create an HTML file with knitr, check this example.

````
  ---
    title: "Untitled"
    author: "SabDeM"
    date: "30 giugno 2015"
    output: html_document
    ---

    A very long list
    ```{r}
    ll <- as.list(rep("A", 10000))
    ll

    ```
````

Another way could be to set the `max.print` option. Default is 10000 you can change this value. Anyway this is just to give you another options I suggest you to don't use this way.

```
options("max.print" = 100)
```

Comment: knitr seems like overkill for recording data output