# R: Save all output printed at the console in R Studio from running a script into .txt

Tags: r, logging, console, output

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096989/how-to-save-all-console-output-to-file-in-r), but neither of the solutions are doing the job. The
external tools like `script`, `screen` or `tmux`, what are they? packages?

Well basically what I want is this:

I have a script whit that code:

```
# my for loop
for (i in 1:10){
  print(i)
}
```

What I would like to save into a .txt file is this (all the things displayed at the console just as they are, when the code is run):

```
> for (i in 1:10){
+   print(i)
+ }
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
>
```

Just very simple line for line. Is there no simple solution for that?

`sink()` is not doing it, it just prints the output not the rest...

`futile.logger`, I tried but I did not work. Would be the right thing to use? I guess it could, but seems to be way beyond my needs.

Comment: Also see [?history](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/savehistory.html)

Comment: I tried it, but it misses the output :(