# Windows task scheduler - Log of a task

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

It is easy with Windows task scheduler to see when a given task was run, if it was successful or not, etc. (the 'History' tab). Nevertheless, I could not find a way to see the logs of a particular task I ran. For instance, I run an R script, it would be awesome to be able to see what was printed in the console.

I woud like to know if this can be done ? If yes, how ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, my solution (for R) was just to generate the log file directly from R following this solution : [How to save all console output to file in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096989/how-to-save-all-console-output-to-file-in-r)