# Exporting g++ compilation error messages from TMB library to a text file

Tags: c++, r, rstudio, sink, tmb

I'm trying to compile a model with gcc (c++) in R (using the TMB package). The errors are so numerous that in Rstudio, I can't even scroll up to see the beginning of them. Therefore, I would like to print everything in the console (messages, errors and warnings) to a text file. This way I could also compare different model outputs (or specifically, their fails).

I tried the following things:

```
fileConn<-file("Fail.txt")
writeLines(compile("Mymodel.cpp"), fileConn) 
close(fileConn)
```

=> Gives me an empty file (which I more or less expected)

```
zz <- file("Fail.txt", open = "wt")
sink(zz, type = "message")
compile("Mymodel.cpp")
sink()
```

=> only prints the final error

What did I overlook?

Comment: Add `sink(zz, type = "output")` after the first `sink`. In this way you divert both `stdout` and `stderr` to the file you choose.

Comment: Tried it, but that still only gives me the final error....

Comment: Are you sure? Please, provide a reproducible example, with expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided your `compile()` function, but I assume it runs a system command that calls `g++` to compile `Mymodel.cpp`.

In this case, the `g++` process will print its error output to stderr. The only way to capture this output using R is to call [`system2()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system2.html) with `stderr=T`. Note that [`system()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html) does not have the capability to capture stderr directly (although it can capture stdout via `intern=T`, and you could add `2>&1` to the shell command to capture stderr along with it, so that's another viable option). [`sink()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sink.html) does not capture system command output; it only captures R output.

I recommend passing variadic arguments from your `compile()` function to the `system2()` call, thus parameterizing whether your call to `compile()` results in `g++`'s stderr going to the terminal or to the return value of your `compile()` function. Here's how this would be done:

```
write('error!','test1.cpp'); ## generate a test file with invalid C++
compile <- function(file,...) system2('g++',file,...);
compile('test1.cpp'); ## output lost to the terminal
## test1.cpp:1:1: error: ‘error’ does not name a type
##  error!
##  ^
output <- compile('test1.cpp',stdout=T,stderr=T); ## capture output
## Warning message:
## running command ''g++' 'test1.cpp' 2>&1' had status 1
output;
## [1] "test1.cpp:1:1: error: ‘error’ does not name a type"
## [2] " error!"
## [3] " ^"
## attr(,"status")
## [1] 1
write(output,'output.txt'); ## write output to a text file
cat(readLines('output.txt'),sep='\n'); ## show it
## test1.cpp:1:1: error: ‘error’ does not name a type
##  error!
##  ^
```

---

If you really want to capture *all* output generated within your `compile()` function, then you can combine the above solution with `sink()` as demonstrated here: [How to save all console output to file in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096989/how-to-save-all-console-output-to-file-in-r).

In this case, I'd recommend scrapping the variadic arguments idea and going with a single additional argument to `compile()`, which will take an output file name to which all output will be written.

This will require several predications on the missingness of the additional argument:

```
write('error!','test1.cpp'); ## generate a test file with invalid C++
compile <- function(file,outputFile) {
    if (!missing(outputFile)) {
        outputCon <- file(outputFile,'wt'); ## require file name
        sink(outputCon);
        sink(outputCon,type='message'); ## must sink messages separately
        warn.old <- options(warn=1)$warn; ## necessary to capture warnings as they occur
    }; ## end if
    cat('some random output 1\n');
    if (!missing(outputFile)) {
        output <- system2('g++',file,stdout=T,stderr=T); ## before flush to get warnings
        sink(); ## force flush before appending system command output
        sink(type='message');
        outputCon <- file(outputFile,'at'); ## must reopen connection for appending
        write(output,outputCon);
        sink(outputCon);
        sink(outputCon,type='message');
    } else {
        system2('g++',file);
    }; ## end if
    cat('some random output 2\n');
    if (!missing(outputFile)) {
        sink();
        sink(type='message');
        options(warn=warn.old);
    }; ## end if
}; ## end compile()
compile('test1.cpp'); ## output lost to the terminal
## some random output 1
## test1.cpp:1:1: error: ‘error’ does not name a type
##  error!
##  ^
## some random output 2
compile('test1.cpp','output.txt'); ## internally capture all output
cat(readLines('output.txt'),sep='\n'); ## show it
## some random output 1
## Warning: running command ''g++' test1.cpp 2>&1' had status 1
## test1.cpp:1:1: error: ‘error’ does not name a type
##  error!
##  ^
## some random output 2
```

Comment: Thank you, I learned something new. However, when I do this, it only creates an empty file again. I also tried system(test1.dpp, intern=T) and system2("test1.cpp", stdout=TRUE,stdout=TRUE) as well, but neither seem to give me the wanted results (only function (x) 
UseMethod("t")
<bytecode: 0x00000000132d7aa0>
<environment: namespace:base>). I'm sorry for gorgetting to mention that compile() is from the TMB package (and doing what you presumes it does)

Comment: In the `system()` and `system2()` calls you've pasted into your comment, you have incorrect shell command syntax; `g++` must be the first word in the command. Also, in your `system2()` call, you've specified `stdout=T` twice, rather than `stdout=T,stderr=T`. Also, the output you pasted looks like the output you get when you run `t;`, IOW the default dump of the base R `t()` function, which is not relevant to this question. Finally, I looked into `TMB::compile()`, and it provides no facility for capturing its system command output, so you can't achieve this requirement with `TMB::compile()`.

Comment: Ok, thank you! And oops, I completely screwed up the copy pasting/retyping. Sorry :s

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I found a simple solution to get a logfile output for `TMB::compile`, which I have not found anywhere else.
As stated  above, sink() does not capture system command output; it only captures R output. 
However, any argument not listed in the function `compile` from library `TMB` are passed as Makeconf variables. Thus, you only have to pass a classical output command with the path to the targeted logfile in a string format:

```
TMB::compile(file = "Mymodel.cpp", "&> /tmp/logfile.log")
```

Comment: a MUCH more elegant approach than the accepted answer!