# How can I capture warning messages from rstan R package's stan() function, when running an R script that calls stan() on the command line?

Tags: r, command-line, stan, rstan

In the R script `Fit12_for_stack.R`, I call `rstan` package's `stan()` function. When I run the `Fit12_for_stack.R` code in an interactive R session, I get these warning messages from `stan()`:

> Warning messages:
>   1: There were 13 divergent transitions after warmup. Increasing adapt_delta above 0.8 may help. 
>   2: Examine the pairs() plot to diagnose sampling problems

When I run the script `Fit12_for_stack.R` on the command line with the command:

```
Rscript Fit12_for_stack.R
```

I get output, but not the warning messages. **How can I capture the `stan()` warning messages when running the R script that calls `stan()` on the command line?**

From the post [How to save all console output to file in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096989/how-to-save-all-console-output-to-file-in-r), I tried adding

```
con <- file("test.log")
sink(con, append=TRUE)
sink(con, append=TRUE, type="message")
```

to the top of the script, but `test.log` again showed output, without `stan()` warning messages.

This is what `Fit12_for_stack.R` looks like:

```
con <- file("test.log")
sink(con, append=TRUE)
sink(con, append=TRUE, type="message")

library("rstan")

J <- 2
L <- 3

X <- matrix(c(98, 22, 42, 99, 68, 61), nrow = L, ncol = J)
N <- matrix(100, nrow = L, ncol = J)

fit <- stan(file="try8.stan",
            data=list(J, L, X, N),
            iter=100, chains=4, seed = 1)
```

This is what `try8.stan` looks like:

```
data{

   int<lower=0> J;
   int<lower=0> L;

   // Declare arrays with integer entries.

   int X[L,J];
   int N[L,J];

}

parameters {

   // Add parameters:
   // - pi_vec = [pi_1, ..., pi_L]
   // - C_vec = [C_11, ..., C_JJ]

   vector<lower=0,upper=1>[L] pi_vec;

   vector<lower=0,upper=1>[J] C_vec;

   matrix<lower=0,upper=1>[L,J] Alpha;

}

transformed parameters {

}

model {

    for (i in 1:L) {
        pi_vec[i] ~ uniform(0,1);
    }

    for (j in 1:J) {
        C_vec[j] ~ uniform(0,1);
    }

    for (i in 1:L) {
        for (j in 1:J) {

            Alpha[i,j] ~ normal(pi_vec[i], sqrt(C_vec[j]*(pi_vec[i])*(1 - pi_vec[i]))) T[0,1];

            // For the (Like = 1) test, have X[i,j] ~ U(0,1),
            // i.e. set the likelihood's density to 1 so that posterior density = prior density.

            X[i,j] ~ uniform(0,1);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Newest update (2.12.1 on Sept. 10, 2016) says rstan now throws warnings even if not in interactive mode. That change might let you capture warnings now.

Comment: Thanks TJ. Did you check the latest version of the manual in response to this post, or is there a way to be automatically alerted every time they come out with a new manual?

Comment: I read the package news whenever I update RStan https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstan/NEWS

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding `stan(..., cores = 2)` and the warning messages were logged.  I skimmed through the [source](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/blob/1b4e19c2f16a3953c2a788ba7eddc76c291587cd/rstan/rstan/R/stanmodel-class.R), and my guess (I could be wrong) is that when `cores = 1`, the warning is only thrown if `R` is in interactive mode (right at the very end of the script).

When `cores` is more than 1, `sink()` does not appear to log the output from the workers, but redirecting the output seems to work, e.g.

```
Rscript Fit12_for_stack.R  > test.Rout
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I tried your solution like so: (1) "cp Fit12_for_stack.R Fit12_for_stack_Wong.R". (2) I deleted the top 3 lines of Fit12_for_stack_Wong.R involving con and sink(). (3) I added "cores = 2" to the stan() call. (4) I ran Rscript Fit12_for_stack_Wong.R > test_Wong.Rout, but the stan() warnings printed to the console and not to test_Wong.Rout. Maybe if I used qsub to submit "Rscript Fit12_for_stack_Wong.R > test_Wong.Rout" to a cluster, the output file for the qsub command would capture the stan() warnings, but I haven't tried that.

Comment: When I tried it, I retained the lines related to `sink()` (i.e. didn't do your step 2 above).  Anyway, seems like your method works, so it's all good!

Comment: Yup, and my mild adjustment of your method works too when sink() is removed. I did steps (1)-(4) and then qsub -q [queue name here] -j yes -e [folder name here] -o [folder name here] run_Wong.sh, where run_Wong.sh calls "Rscript Fit12_for_stack_Wong.R", and the output file run_Wong.sh.o1551988 gets saved to [folder name here] with stan() warnings.

Answer (score 0):

So I removed the lines

```
con <- file("test.log")
sink(con, append=TRUE)
sink(con, append=TRUE, type="message")
```

from

```
Fit12_for_stack.R
```

and ran the program with the command

```
R CMD BATCH Fit12_for_stack.R
```

This produced an output file

```
Fit12_for_stack.Rout
```

with the stan() warnings included.