# Write R console to file with source() despite errors

Tags: r

I want to capture the input and output of R into a separate text file. I found that the best way to do so is a combination of `sink()` and `source()` commands ([How to save all console output to file in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096989/how-to-save-all-console-output-to-file-in-r)).

My problem is that in some data constellations, I get error messages. The exeution of the script via `source()` seems to stop right after an error occurs. However, I would like to run the script to the end and simply record everything, including the errors.

How can I adapt my approach to "skip" errors?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `tryCatch()` for every error.

For example,

```
tryCatch({
    print('This line works well');
    stop('that line contains an error')
}, error = function(e){})
```