# capture console output of multiple commands and write to txt

Tags: r, console, capture

im aware of `sink()` and `capture.output()`. Somehow I cant get my desired result.

#### example of my codeblock

```
mtcars[1:2,1:2]
#this is awesome,
mtcars[1:2,1:2] %>% rowMeans(.)
```

#### Desired output in my txt file: Must look 100% like in my console:

> ```
> > mtcars[1:2,1:2]
>               mpg cyl
> Mazda RX4      21   6
> Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6
> >     #this is awesome,
> >     mtcars[1:2,1:2] %>% rowMeans(.)
>     Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Wag 
>          13.5          13.5
> ```

#### Preudocode

It would be nice to have something like this:

```
console2txt(file="text.txt")
    mtcars[1:2,1:2]
    #this is awesome,
    mtcars[1:2,1:2] %>% rowMeans(.)
dev.off()
```

Is there a solution to caputure the entire console of a "script block".

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096989/how-to-save-all-console-output-to-file-in-r

Comment: I tried out the solution in the post. It works. Thank you. Yet is there a more compact solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I do this with [RMarkdown.](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-3.html)

````
---
output: rtf_document
---
```{r}
mtcars[1:2,1:2]
#this is awesome,
mtcars[1:2,1:2] %>% rowMeans(.)
```
````