# How to save everything from Console to a text file while executing an R script using "remoteScript" of Microsoft R?

Tags: r, console, microsoft-r, r-server

I'm curious to know if there is a way to save everything from the R console to a text file when an R script is submitted and executed "remotely" from Microsoft R client to Microsoft R server using the command `remoteScript()` or `remoteExecute()`.

For example, consider a simple R script **`'test.R'`** as follows:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(100)
mean(x)
```

I know, to save all from the console, it can be executed in a Local R session as follows:

#### Local R session:

```
# Create a text file to save all from console 
logfile <- file("C:/.../MyLog1.txt")
sink(logfile, append = TRUE)
sink(logfile, append = TRUE, type = "message")

# Execute in the local R session
source("C:/.../test.R", echo = TRUE, max.deparse.length = 1000000)

sink()
sink(type = "message")
```

The log file **`'MyLog1.txt'`**, as expected, has everything from the console:

```
> set.seed(123)
> x <- rnorm(100)
> mean(x)
[1] 0.09040591
```

Similarly, the same script can be executed with `remoteScript()` after connecting to the R server.

#### Remote R session:

```
# Connect to the server and create a remote session
remoteLogin(...)

# Go back to the local R session
pause()

# Create a text file to save all from console 
logfile <- file("C:/.../MyLog2.txt")
sink(logfile, append = TRUE)
sink(logfile, append = TRUE, type = "message")

# Execute in the remote R session
remoteScript("C:/.../test.R")

sink()
sink(type = "message")
```

But the log file **`'MyLog2.txt'`** looks different, as shown below:

```
[1] 0.09040591
$success
[1] TRUE

$errorMessage
[1] ""

$outputParameters
list()

$consoleOutput
[1] "[1] 0.09040591\r\n"

$changedFiles
list()

$backgroundUpdate
[1] 0
```

It has only the "Output" and some additional information. Each line of the code with `'>'` command prompt was not printed like `'MyLog1.txt'`. It may be because there is no option like `echo=TRUE` for `remoteScript()`.

Can anybody help me out with any alternative?

Thanks..

Comment: Have you seen [How to save all console output to file in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7096989/4752675)  Note the comments in particular.

Comment: Yes. I'm using remoteScript() instead of source() to run the script in a remote server.  But the result is not the same - only output line is printed,  input lines are not printed.