# save console output in different files with sink in R

Tags: r, sink

Similar to this question [How to save all console output to file in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096989/how-to-save-all-console-output-to-file-in-r)

Though i want the output in two different logs.

```
con <- file("test.log")
sink(con, append=TRUE)
sink(con, append=TRUE, type="message")

print(1+1)

#clc <- function() cat("\f")
#clc()

con2 <- file("test2.log")
sink(con, append=TRUE)
sink(con, append=TRUE, type="message")

print(2+2)
```

If i do this, R saves both 2 and 4 into test.log. test2.log just gets ignored and is not created. How can i achieve to save them seperately? I also played around with clearing console but that didnt seem to work out either.

Kind regards!

Comment: You never use `con2` as argument for `sink`.

Comment: Well, that's correct. I just didn't see that. Stupid of me, but thanks for correcting me.