# how can I redirect system command and its output in r?

Tags: r

I am using `system` command to find files on `ubuntu`, and trying to redirect the result on screen to a txt file, as following example.

```
# make file
system("touch a.txt")
system("touch b.txt")
system("touch c.txt")
system("touch d.txt")

sink("t.txt")

 c("a.txt", "b.txt")%>% lapply(function(f) {
  system(sprintf("find -name %s", f)) 
}) 
sink()
```

but the result turns out to be a list with O's inside.
Please advise how I can achieve that. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save all console output to file in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096989/how-to-save-all-console-output-to-file-in-r)

Comment: This [link](https://statisticsglobe.com/r-save-all-console-input-output-to-file) also seems relevant

Comment: thanks. I'd checked this post earlier. unfortunately, I just got list with empty elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `intern = TRUE` option which returns `system` result directly into the `R` environment:

```
c("a.txt", "b.txt" , "test.txt") %>% lapply(function(f) {
  system(sprintf("find -name %s", f), intern = T)
}) 

[[1]]
[1] "./a.txt"

[[2]]
[1] "./b.txt"

[[3]]
character(0)
```